# GCM services query

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM services for my application to recieve data from the cloud.

Unfortnately, GCM does not respond or device does not recieve any commands from GCM if the GOOGLE play is not signed in , on the device ?

IS GOOGLE PLAY SIGN UP compulsory to recieve GCM ?

Also if through my application i need to find whether device is SIGN into GOOGLE PLAY
IS it available ?

Any help would be accepted >> THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: not google play , you need to sing up any google a/c for receiving push notification with your device/emulator

Comment: You don't need to have your app uploaded to Google Play to make GCM work (AFAIK, only Google App-In needs that). And you don't need your app to be signed either (debug signature is enough). But devices must have Google Play installed, I think that is the requirement, and of course you will need the ID of the account registered in Google Play.

Comment: Thanks , thats the kind of information i am looking for.

Comment: Can I get details if the device is signed in with a google account ?

Comment: I believe it depends on the version of Android the device is running. On 4.0 at least you do not need a Google Play account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) here are the two points that are important:

> It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the
>   Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running
>   Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to
>   deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store.
>
> It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0
>   devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their
>   mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices
>   running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

So if the device is running 4.0.4 or higher a Google account is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

No Google play sign up is not compulsory to receive GCM. But remember if you are testing on emulator make sure it is GOOGLE API and not android. You can find a step by step guide to implement GCM using emulator and PHP [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)